# MFC: Enable wait cursor for a CFormView while CFormView is disabled?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have no problem setting a wait cursor via `WM_SETCURSOR` and no problem disabling the form using `EnableWindow()` but I can't disable the window and get a wait cursor at the same time?   When the Window (`CFormView`) is disabled there are no calls to `WM_SETCURSOR` so the cursor doesn't change. `BeginWaitCursor()` and `EndWaitCursor()` don't help.   I can do it over the `CMainFrame` but I only want the form to be disabled and all the other tabs and windows to work properly.

What am I missing to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Use CWaitcursor

Answer (score -1):

When you define `CWaitCursor`, the [Wait Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwaitcursor-class) will appear throughout the existence of the code block, regardless of the window being enabled or disabled.

Comment: This doesn't provide a solution. As written, the OP *"only want\[s\] the form to be disabled"*, with everything still fully operational, and a cursor that communicates this.